# Is it possible to add Rootobject with subclasses in one go to Entity Framwork?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I'm trying to Deserialize data into an object, and then add that object to a sqlite database with Entity Framework.

The first part is working fine.

But if try to add the object to the database I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Client' cannot be
tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being 
tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a 
given key value is attached. Consider using 
'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key 
values.'
```

Is it not possible to add the Rootobject with all the subclasses in one go?

Here is my code, I did not include all the sub classes.
All classes has an Id field:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
//Add headers etc. ...
var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
string? content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var TimeEntries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(content);

using (var database = new DataContext())
{
    database.Add(TimeEntries);
    database.SaveChanges();
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Rootobject>? RootObjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Link>? Links { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Time_Entry>? Time_Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client>? Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project>? Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task>? Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User_Assignment>? User_Assignments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task_Assignment>? Task_Assignments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<External_Reference>? External_References { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder)
    {
        dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=data.db");
    }
}
public class Rootobject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<Time_Entry>? Time_entries { get; set; }
    public int Per_page { get; set; }
    public int Total_pages { get; set; }
    public int Total_entries { get; set; }
    public int ?Next_page { get; set; }
    public int ?Previous_page { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public Link? Links { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *Is it not possible to add the Rootobject with all the subclasses in one go?* - it is, but it sounds like youre running into a fairly typical problem when deser'ing directly to a DB entity graph, in that the JSON might specify (related) entities in their entirety multiple times, so you end up with several different object instances with the same id. Processing the graph to dedupe the various instances down to one before you add to the context is one way round it

Comment: To give a definite answer we'd need to see the JSON, but imagine two people at the same address: `[{ name:John, address:{ id:1,street:"1 infinite loop"}},{ name:Jane, address:{ id:1,street:"1 infinite loop"}}]` - desering this would casuse two instances of an Address object with ID 1. If you then add John and Jane to the Persons DbSet, EF will kick off when you add Jane second, because it already knows about an Address instance with ID 1. A JSON serializer lib typically won't see the second address id be the same as the first and reuse the old instance it made

Comment: To resolve it you might comb through all your persons adding the addresses to a `Dictionary<int, Address>` if the ID is not in the dict, or replacing the person's Address with the one from the dict if it's already known. This way everyone with address ID 1 uses the same instance of the object and EF can wire up the relationships correctly

Comment: Thanks, I can see the issue now. 
To solve this would I have to lookup the addressID in the database manually to check if its already there or do I get some help from EF?

Comment: If there's a chance it'll already be in the DB you can simplify your life with `dbContext.YourThing.Find(the_id)` - if it returns null, add the thing youre processing as the enitity, if it's in the db it will be returned. In either case it's now known to the change tracker, so the next time Find is invoked it will be EF's local cache giving you the object, so it makes your wiring up simple... There are other ways to trick the change tracker into thinking that an object it didn't see before now is one downloaded from the DB but generally I find it simplest to just download the real item

Comment: In the above example, like `foreach(var p in people){` `var a = db.Addresses.Find(p.Address.Id);` `if(a == null) db.Addresses.Add(p.Address);` `else p.Address = a; }` I think (I'm AFK now) - first time ID 123 is seen, Find will hit the DB, then either it comes from db and replaces person's address, or it is created from this person's addressed. Next time the same cached address will be used (it might be from db or from john)

Comment: If you know these ents are all new/don't want to bother the DB, then maybe `var d = new Dictionary<int, Address>();` `foreach(var p in people){` `if(d.TryGetValue(p.Address.Id, out var a)) p.Address = a;` `else d[p.Address.Id] = p.Address;` - if the dictionary saw that ID before, put that object from dict as the address, else the id was not known so put the current person's address in the dict